# How to pass a jQuery selector chain to my plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm quite new to jQuery and i need to solve a selection problem. I have many triggers with `class="trigger"` on which jQuery plugin function `myFunc` is invoked.

Triggers can be images or links and each trigger must **refer** to an input field (textbox or textarea) with `class="target"`.

Here is an example, but please note that `targets` may **precede** or **follow** `triggers` eventually with some elements in **between**:

```
<a class="trigger">trigger 1</a>
<input class="target" type="text" /><!-- target for trigger 1 -->

<a class="trigger">trigger 2</a>
<textarea class="target"></textarea><!-- target for trigger 2 -->
```

**The problem** is i need to pass a `targetSelector` (like `.next('.target')` or somthing else depending on DOM) to my plugin, in order to get each target element for each trigger:

```
$('.trigger').myFunc({ // Plugin invokation
   targetSelector : <code here> // Pass something like .next('.target')
});

(function($) { // Plugin defininition
    $.fn.myFunc = function(options) {

       this.each(function() { // Iterate each trigger
          var target = <code here>; // Get target for current trigger
       };

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you make `targetSelector` a function, where `this` refers to the current `.trigger`  and it returns the corresponding target:

```
$('.trigger').myFunc({ // Plugin invokation
   targetSelector : function() {
       return $(this).next('.target')
   }
});
```

Which can be implemented with [`.call()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
$.fn.myFunc = function(options) {

   this.each(function() { // Iterate each trigger
      var target = options.targetSelector.call(this);
   };

};
```

This gives you the greatest flexibility and you can perform any DOM traversal you want in this function.

Of course you can make it more sophisticated and make `targetSelector` accept both, a  selector string and a function, and then handle the value accordingly.

Example:

```
$.fn.myFunc = function(options) {
   var selectorFunc = $.isFunction(options.targetSelector) ? 
                         options.targetSelector :
                         function() {
                            return $(options.targetSelector);
                         };

   this.each(function() { // Iterate each trigger
      var target = selectorFunc.call(this);
   };

};
```

Comment: This would only find the ones after the trigger, he mentions that the targets may be before the trigger element, which would require checking also, .prev

Comment: @Patrick: It's just a matter of setting up the function passed to `targetSelector` accordingly. I think the question was more about the general approach than a specific situation.

Comment: I like your answer and upvoted it. But how this can handle (extremely rare) situations where target1 precedes trigger1 while target2 follows trigger2?

Comment: @Gremo: That depends on the context. If both elements `trigger` and `target` are the only elements with that class inside their parent, you can use `$(this).siblings('.target')` to get the `.target` sibling, no matter whether it is before or after.

Comment: All is working fine except maybe your function (when passing a string) is not working. Passing "this" as string results in target = document. I mean the whole document object not the trigger itself. Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean the second example? I forgot to change the call from `options.targetSelector.call(this)` to `selectorFunc.call(this)`... did you mean this?

Answer (score 2):

use a custom attribute instead of relying on .next or .prev as you would have to check prev and next to see which one retrives the right now.

Example

```
<a class="trigger" mytarget="Target1">trigger 1</a>
<input class="target" type="text" id="Target1" /><!-- target for trigger 1 -->

<a class="trigger" mytarget="Target2">trigger 2</a>
<textarea class="target" id="Target2"></textarea><!-- target for trigger 2 -->

<script>
$('.trigger').myFunc();

(function($) { // Plugin defininition
    $.fn.myFunc = function(options) {

       this.each(function() { // Iterate each trigger
          var targetName = $(this).attr("mytarget");

          var target = $("#"+targetName); // Get target for current trigger
       };

    };
})(jQuery);


</script>
```

Comment: If you use custom HTML attributes, you should use HTML5 `data-*` attributes: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: you dont have to use the data-* html5 features, using them is only to help make your markup is "valid", which does have advantages but is not required.

Comment: @PatrickEvans fine thanks. Upvote for the idea, but still i want it to validate ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.trigger').each(function() //split your selects
{
    $(this).myFunc({  
        //your code here
    });    
});
```